# SCRIPT70: Permission denied IE9

Tags: javascript, permissions, internet-explorer-9

I am getting the strange error "`SCRIPT70: Permission denied jquery.js, line 21 character 67`" on IE-9. Searched on google but could not find anything except a bug on CKEditor.

Position it showed just contains following:

```
P=navigator.userAgent,xa=false,Q=[],M,ca=Object.prototype.toString,da=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,ea=Array.prototype.push,R=Array.prototype.slice,V=Array.prototype.indexOf;c.fn=c.prototype={init:function(a,b){var d,f;if(!a)return this;if(a.nodeType){this.context=this[0]=a;this.length=1;return this}if(typeof a==="string")if((d=Oa.exec(a))&&(d[1]||!b))if(d[1]){f=b?b.ownerDocument||b:s;if(a=Sa.exec(a))if(c.isPlainObject(b)){a=[s.createElement(a[1])];
```

anyone run into this error?

**Additional Info:**We open an iframe and call some javascript functions inside this iframe.

thanks.

Comment: You need to reproduce it with a non-minified version so you can see the line of code which actually causes it.

Comment: i just realized, it does not allow any script file. I could see a quite simple line in a non-minified js file. 
var imageType = jQuery("#imageType").val();
we open an iframe and try to run javascript inside could this be the reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SCRIPT70 error in IE9 occurs most likely when your iframe is calling some javascript (especially if it affects the parent page - e.g. hash change of parent url)

Check that your iframe's host/protocol/port number matches.
IE9 is exceptionally strict about the host name(down to the www portion in my case) and document.domain did not seem to provide a workaround for that.

Encountered this issue and fixed it while dealing with multiple iframes, hope this helps others with the same issue.

Comment: I'm getting this with window.postMessage from an iFrame to parent cross origin domain on IE11. With Edge Browser it works fine. Can someone explain the "host/protocol/port number matches" more in detail please?

Answer (score 2):

```
function Sizzle( selector, context, results, seed ) {
  var match, elem, m, nodeType,

  // QSA vars
  i, groups, old, nid, newContext, newSelector;

  // MY EDIT - this try/catch seems to fix IE 'permission denied' errors as described here:
  // http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14535

  try{
    document === document; //may cause permission denied
  }
  catch(err){
    document = window.document; //resets document, and no more permission denied errors.
  }

  if ( ( context ? context.ownerDocument || context : preferredDoc ) !== document ) {
    setDocument( context );
  }

  //...... snip .........//
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xqb4s/

Comment: You should add some explaining text to your answer. Also, I don't see how your jsfiddle demonstrates anything

Comment: you need to edit your jquery-*.js and add the try catch within the sizzle function (the function causing the access denied).  I don't like playing in the jquery file but it does solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I was having this exact problem with IE9 and in fact, it happens with IE11 as well.

My problem was I was opening a website via `http` (i.e.  http://mywebsite.com) and an iframe within my code was trying to access a portion of the website using `https`.  This was causing the error. Once I accessed the website using `https`, the error went away.  A old bookmark was the cause of it using `http` and the site had been updated with `https` so check your URLS.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access any of your iframe's contents if it points to a different domain than the parent site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with select element in your script maybe your problem is like mine

[SCRIPT70: Permission denied when adding options to select element from a recently closed iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169779/script70-permission-denied-when-adding-options-to-select-element-from-a-recentl)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I encountered this error. In the application I am working, I'm using **TinyMce text editor** for our email composer. This creates an **iframe** which contains the objects I need for an email composer. After seeing many blogs about the said error, I tried to programmatically remove the TinyMce text editor object then triggered the redirection. And it WORKED!

Answer (score -2):

Facing a similar issue (maybe not with jquery.js but the same error description) the solution was a bit different from above. Actually I have searched for other iexplore.exe lines in regedit.  I have found other two and changed it to 1 and it worked then.

```
hkey_local_machine\software\microsoft\internet explorer\main\featurecontrol\feature_protocol_lockdown 
hkey_local_machine\software\microsoft\internet explorer\main\featurecontrol\feature_internet_shell_folders
```

Answer (score -2):

If you run a 64-bit OS, make sure the value of this key is also set to 1: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\**Wow6432Node**\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_OBJECT_CACHING\\iexplore.exe`

Without this key we had random `SCRIPT70: Permission denied` errors in Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score -3):

Tip from this one page should help: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/strange-behaviour-in-ie9

> Make sure that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_OBJECT_CACHING\iexplore.exe is not set to 0 (it should be 1 or missing)

Comment: Uuhhm, do they really expect me to tell this to all IE9 users who visit my public site?

Comment: This is the worst idea ever. You cannot expect me to tell my 30 million users to change their registry. Are you serious?