# IE9 Permission Denied when writing to a window - ExtJS 4 App

Tags: javascript, extjs4, internet-explorer-9

```
var display_setting = "toolbar=yes, location=no, directories=yes, menubar=yes,";
    display_setting += "scrollbars=yes, width=750, height=600, left=100, top=25";
    var printwin = window.open('', 'printwin', display_setting )
    printwin.document.open()
    printwin.document.write("Testing")
    printwin.document.close()
```

Why does the above code generate a "Permission Denied" error in IE9, but works perfectly fine on Firefox or Chrome? Is there a work around? It is an ExtJS 4.1 application is running on an intranet from a single domain. It uses the ExtJS history feature which may be a factor.

Thanks

Comment: Working in mine. But can't close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all this, it turns out that one of the included scripts contained the line

```
document.domain = document.domain;
```

Everything works after it is removed.

Answer (score 4):

I have tested with the above code, in IE I have found only one issue, that is in the last line you haven't declared the object win... if you give the details of your requirement then I will help. I have modified your code and tried its works fine for me in IE.

Here is the test code. If you want to close the window use `printwin.close()` instead of `printwin.document.close()`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openwindowIE(){
var display_setting = "toolbar=yes, location=no, directories=yes, menubar=yes,";
    display_setting += "scrollbars=yes, width=750, height=600, left=100, top=25";
    var printwin = window.open('', 'printwin', display_setting )
    printwin.document.open()
    printwin.document.write("Testing")
    printwin.document.close()
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="openwindowIE()" value="go"  />
```

Comment: Yes, I think it must be something to do with the intranet site, it uses ExtJS 4.1. It may be intefering in some way I can't see

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, IE thinks, that about:blank (which you are trying to open, I guess) is an insecure website and thus you aren't allowed to communicate with it.

If I'm not mistaken, you could open any other (empty) html document and write in it, instead.

Comment: Actually, the error changes from "Permission Denied" to "Access Denied"

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like IE8 has worse security policies. I have no clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a long shot but have you closed all IE windows and tested this? The possibility I am thinking about is that while testing you may have opened a window named `printwin` and then you navigated away from the base page (or opened it in a new tab or trying to open more than one window named `printwin`) and are again trying to open the window with name `printwin`. The `printwin` window was already open but the base page does not have permission to access it since it is not the *original opener* of the page.

The key point here is that the window name should always be *unique*.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var display_setting = "toolbar=yes, location=no, directories=yes, menubar=yes,";
display_setting += "scrollbars=yes, width=750, height=600, left=100, top=25";

var printwin = window.open('about:blank', 'printwin', display_setting);

printwin.document.open();
printwin.document.write("Testing");

printwin.close();
```

[test](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/w4JJ4/)

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352057/script70-permission-denied-ie9 and this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/strange-behaviour-in-ie9#14737000002672231