# IE 10 Cache issue?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, caching

I have a very simple page that is loading 4 scripts.

- jquery 2.0.3
- jquery ui 1.10.3
- knockout 3.0.0
- knockout mapping 2.4.1

This only happens in IE. I have tried it in both 10 & 11;

I navigate to the url and the page loads fine. if I refresh the page still OK. If I go to the hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the address bar expecting it reload, it does but I get `SCRIPT70: Permission denied` errors, saying permission denied. Any ideas? Is this a local security settings policy with IE?

Here is the markup:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>TEST
      <script src="/MyVirtualDir/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/MyVirtualDir/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/MyVirtualDir/Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
      <script src="/MyVirtualDir/Scripts/knockout.mapping-2.4.1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using [any iframes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5352057/1671639)? or the entire html is just the markup?

Comment: The above is the exact markup.

Comment: Try it with a `<!DOCTYPE html>`, perhaps? IE does all sorts of quirky things without a doctype.

Comment: It's not a problem with DOCTYPE

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help but this worked for me in IE10

Here's something to try:

`Make sure that HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_OBJECT_CACHING\iexplore.exe is not set to 0 (it should be 1 or missing)`

Reference: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/strange-behaviour-in-ie9

I don't think it has anything to do with jquery/js

Or Try this: `Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default"`

Comment: Doesn't seem reasonable that I would have to expect a registry change to fix the issue.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to do it...It fixed mine. Also, If you are worried about messing up registry, try it  check to see if it works and then revert back the change.

Comment: How about all the users who have no business changing the reg?

Comment: Ok try this: Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default"

Comment: What is the settings that causes the issue, instead of a blind reset.